# Difference between "vanish" and "disappear"

Tags: differences, verbs

What is the difference between these words, exactly? Both mean to stop existing or to become invisible.

[vanish](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/vanish)

> He turned around and vanished into the house.
>
> My glasses seem to have vanished.
>
> All hopes of a peaceful settlement had now vanished.

[disappear](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/disappear)

> The plane disappeared behind a cloud.
>
> Her nervousness quickly disappeared once she was on stage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Vanish* has a sense of suddenness or mystery or finality about it that *disappear* lacks.

In your examples, I would use "disappeared into the house." instead of "vanished into the house." The other two "vanish" examples are fine.

I think if you were to change your next example to, "The plane vanished behind a cloud." it would imply that it was never seen again. Disappeared doesn't have that sense.

In your last example, you could say "Her nervousness vanished once she was on stage."

Comment: Just to be sure, I get it right: *"My glasses had disappeared but I found them." - "My glasses had vanished and I never found them." - "Where are my glasses? I just turned around for a moment and now they are vanished."* --- And for the nervousness I could say: *"Before my first time on stage I was nervous, but the nervousness vanished once I was on stage." - "Whenever I go on stage my nervousness disappears."* (So in the former sentence I mean that I was nervous just one-time, in the latter sentence that I'm always nervous before I go on stage.)

Comment: I would write your examples like this: "My glasses disappeared, but I found them." "My glasses vanished." (You don't need "and I never found them.") "Where are my glasses? I just turned around for a momement and they vanished." And I think your other sentences are fine as you wrote them.

Answer (score 2):

To *[vanish](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/vanish)* indicates:

> to disappear suddenly and/or in a way that you cannot explain

and to *disappear* is less out of the ordinary.